# Java Files.createFile Docker volume atomic?

Tags: java, linux, docker, io

I'm using:

```
Files.createFile("/tmp/marker.txt")
```

from within two different Docker that are mounting the same Docker volume. The Javadoc is mentioning that this operation is atomic and therefore only one of the attempt will succeed:

> Creates a new and empty file, failing if the file already exists. The
> check for the existence of the file and the creation of the new file
> if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with
> respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the
> directory.

Is this operation still behaving the same in this scenario?

Comment: My suspicion is that this might depend on [which volume driver is used](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-driver). But then again I'd suspect most/all to correctly handle atomic file creation.

Comment: There are enough SO questions around bind-mounts not correctly synching to the container filesystem that I'd be suspicious here.  It may also depend on the specific Docker implementation; a VM-based solution like Minikube or Docker Desktop might behave differently from Docker directly on native Linux.  If you just want some sort of distributed lock, can you use a database transaction or a system like Redis, rather than the filesystem?

Comment: @DavidMaze we're still investigating the possibilities; do you have 1 or 2 links about the SO questions?